# Going from a value inside $[-1,1]$ to a value in another range

Tags: arithmetic, transformation

How does one calculate the value within range $-1.0$ to $1.0$ to be a number within the range of e.g. $0$ to $200$, or $0$ to $100$ etc. ?

Comment: For example $x ↦ 100(x + 1)$? Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have numbers $x$ in the range $[a,b]$ and you want to transform them to numbers $y$ in the range $[c,d]$ you need to do this:

$$y=(x-a)\frac{d-c}{b-a}+c$$

Comment: Thanks. What is the name/tag of such a formula?

Comment: I'd say it's an affine transformation.

Comment: This is brilliant!! I'm surprised I've never seen something like this before.  I knew what I was trying to do was simple, yet I couldn't do it mentally.

Comment: That's slope intercept form of line equation and that's brilliant indeed.

Comment: Thanks it works, but why?

Comment: can you explain how you got to this formula?

Comment: I guess this doesn't work if the scale (distribution?) changes. I have a number ranging from [0, 1] which should map to [-1, 1], but 0.25 would map to 0.

Comment: @RayKoopa: In your example, $0.25$ maps to $-0.5$, as it should. You just have to do the math right ...

Comment: @MattL. I'm afraid those weird mappings were given to me and I had to somehow transform between them with the above samples. It turned out the first range is now only between [0, 0.5], and now it makes sense as y = (x - 0.25) * 4.

Comment: @MattL. How is this affine transformation ? It does not fit as "tranform" , "scale" , "shear" or "rotation" .

Comment: @Talespin_Kit: By definition, $y=ax+b$ is an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).

Comment: @MattL.Could you please be more specific. I am unable to see how line equation has anything to do with it.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit: Did you check the link? It's all there.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful

Answer (score 8):

A short proof of Matt L.'s answer:

We want a function $f: [a, b] \rightarrow [c, d]$ such that

$$
\begin{alignat}{2}
f&(&a) &= c \\
f&(&b) &= d.
\end{alignat}
$$

If we assume the function is to be linear (that is, the output scales as the input does), then

$$\dfrac{d - c}{b - a} = \dfrac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}.$$
Simplifying yields the desired formula for $y = f(x)$.

Comment: An alternative way to see this: $t = (x-a)/(b-a)$ maps from $[a, b]$ to $[0, 1]$. Then $t (d-c) + c$ maps $t$ from $[0, 1]$ to $[c, d]$.