# An equation to map values from one range to another

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need a formula (preferably something I can write with JavaScript, so simple arithmetic) that will map my value that is between 0.5 and 1, to a new value between 0 and 1.  My brain is dead, this seems trivial, yet I can't say I ever learned how to do this.  I'm sure someone here can help!

```
.5 => 0
.6 => .2
.7 => .4
.8 => .6
.9 => .8
1 => 1
```

**Update**

I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377169/calculating-a-value-inside-one-range-to-a-value-of-another-range) which is excellent for linear mappings!  My linear mapping equation is $y=2x-1$

And what if I wanted something non-linear?

```
.5 => 0
.75 => .25
.875 => .5
1 => 1
```

Comment: It depends on the properties you want for the mapping. How smooth should the mapping be? What are the derivatives at the start and end? Splines might be useful, or a Lagrange interpolating polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a polynomial function work for you? If so, just construct the Lagrange or Newton-form interpolating polynomial. If you don't know how to do this, WolframAlpha has an interpolating polynomial calculator: http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/Polynomials.html.